# Powershell Script access local file instead of a web page

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, offline

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script that needs to retrieve a file from a web page. The problem is that the machine that I need to run the script on can't be connected to the internet. I have to work offline for security purposes.

I'll download the file, transfer it to my machine and change the script, I want it to retrieve the file from a local folder instead of connecting to the web page.

I'm new to PowerShell, but I'm guessing that if I changed the following lines(just a sample), the script will work fine.

```
$varable1URL = "https://domainname/main/whatever.something"
$varable1URL = "https://domainname/main/whatever.something"
```

Comment: You'll need to provide far more context, especially code, and outline a specific problem before we can help you. Depending on what you want to do, you may (probably will) need completely different cmdlets in your script to retrieve from a website vs. retrieve from a  local file.

Comment: I'm aware of that and I agree with you, I saw some kind of conversion functions that I'm planning to remove once I direct the script to a local file. the code is too long and complicated to be shared @JeffZeitlin

Comment: You need not share the entire code, only enough to demonstrate the problem - what we call a [mcve].